# Query timestamp stored as a number oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have an Oracle table with a timestamp stored as a number:

```
TASK_DATE NUMBER(15)
```

When I query the table with a number, oracle returns data:

```
SELECT TASK_DATE from MY_TABLE where TASK_DATE>156912000;
```

However, I would like to be able to use an actual date and the following fails

```
SELECT TASK_DATE from MY_TABLE where TASK_DATE>TO_TIMESTAMP ('2020-02-20','YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with the query

Comment: My sympathies that you have to work with a database where they store a date as a number

Comment: What is the logic behind that numbers?

Comment: @kevinsky - thanks for the sympathy, much appreciated :)

Comment: @Tejash The number is a unix timestamp in a legacy database I have not created. Ideally, it would be stored in a different type of field such as a date or an oracle timestamp but I do not have control over the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timestamp looks like the number of seconds in the Unix epoch -- since 1970-01-01.  So:

```
TASK_DATE > (DATE '2020-02-20' - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60
```

That said, the value `156912000` does not correspond to `'2020-02-20'`, so it is unclear what the number really represents.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, your answer is much appreciated. You are correct, it is Unix Epoc and both were supposed to be two different dates. Awesome!